# MVC Json getting null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework

For some reason, I am getting null value returned for Princ_Comments field, but it
contains data.  What could be the problem?

Json Output:

[{"ID":"ACL","Name":"A.C. Lyau Company","Princ_Comments":null}]

Model:

```
    public class PrincComments
    {
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Princ_Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
            public JsonResult GetHTML5Json_PrincComments(string id)
            {
                 id = "ACL";                    
                var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<PrincComments>("Select [ID], [Name], [Princ Comments] From View_Principle_Active where ID = '" + id + "'");                

                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Comment: `[Princ Comments]` or `[Princ_Comments]` ?

Comment: My database has the field as [Princ Comments], but the entity framework (edmx) that was created shows it has [Princ_Comments].  I tried it with another field [Address 1] and get null as well.  Something with blank space in the field name causing this problem.

Comment: try using alias `Select [ID], [Name], [Princ Comments] as [Princ_Comments] From`

Comment: That worked.  How to give points to you?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [**`SqlQuery<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) it says that properties match the columns of the query.

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given type.
>   The type can be any type that **has properties that match the names of
>   the columns returned from the query**, or can be a simple primitive
>   type. The type does not have to be an entity type. The results of this
>   query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object
>   returned is an entity type.

To fix the problem, you can use column alias.

```
Select [ID], [Name], [Princ Comments] as [Princ_Comments]
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment that Yuliam recommendation worked so that's great. Always nice to get a quick answer. This is sample code right? I assume the id assignment in code was temporary for testing purposes. The way that method is written is begging for an sql injection.

```
    [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetHTML5Json_PrincComments(string id)
        {
             id = "ACL";                    
            var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<PrincComments>("Select [ID], [Name], [Princ Comments] as 'Princ_Comments'  From View_Principle_Active where ID = '" + id + "'");                

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```